# Create entity relationships between bundles of differents providers

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, event-listener

I'm developing my first Symfony2 Bundle "distributable" by packagist.org and have a few questions regarding how to relate the "user entity" from: "the  actual project", to: "this external bundle".

What I do:

1. I created a GIT repository specifically for my bundle.
2. I have created and configured the composer.json file, as explained in packagist.org
3. Set the user entity from the general config.yml `/app/config/config.yml` 
   to send as parameter to the bundle .

```php
// KDRMKLabs\TicketBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration.php
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('kdr_ticket');

        $rootNode->children()
            ->scalarNode('user_class')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
            ->end()
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

```yml
# app\config\config.yml
kdr_ticket:
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
```

```php
// KDRMKLabs\TicketBundle\DependencyInjection\KDRTicketExtension.php
class KDRTicketExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.xml');

        $container->setParameter('kdr_ticket.model.user.class', $config['user_class']);
    }
}
```

4. Ticket Entity

```php
/**
 * Ticket
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="kdr_ticket")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Ticket
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * How I can tell to Doctrine that this object is the specified in config.yml ?
     */
    private $user;

    ...
}
```

5. Using the User Entity when you install the bundle or when the database is updated for the first time after installation of the bundle

How Can I use the "user entity" specified in config.yml to create relations of the form "ManyToOne" when you update the database with the command `doctrine:schema:update --force`

I appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Comment: This might help: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html but associating entities across independent bundles can be tricky.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is just what I needed.